# How to use Live Server extention in VS code IDE to run NodeJs, Express Web App

Tags: node.js, express, vscode-extensions, liveserver, npm-live-server

I've been trying to get my Live server extension on VS code to to automatically refresh my browser every time I make changes to my code but its not been able to work. Normally when I'm using it for front end ONLY  it works perfectly but when I start my server using `nodemon app.js` it doesn't work

I tried changing the live server PORT from default (5500) to 3000 which is the same as my express port but it still fails to reload my browser